# disable fall manager Nao-robot

Tags: nao-robot

I'm trying to disable the fall Manager of my Nao-robot.
And the former web page won't load. I can find the log-in site, but after I've typed the password nothing happens at all.

I need to turn the fall manager off! I've read that I can modify the ALmotion file, but I have no clue whatsoever how to do that.

Thank you for any help

Comment: About the webpage not loading, you should contact the support...

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the "disabling option" programatically with this command:

```
motion ALProxy( "ALMotion" );
motion.setMotionConfig( [["ENABLE_DISACTIVATION_OF_FALL_MANAGER", True]] );
```

as found there:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/nao/doc/reference-documentation/naoqi/motion/reflexes-fall-manager.html